# To solve a simple heist

Tags: mathematics, story, rebus, music

It happened by chance really. I was walking out from the bank when a man ran into me while rushing out. During our collision a piece of paper fell from his pocket.

I quickly picked it up and tried to call out to him, but he had vanished. I then looked at the note and was instantly intrigued.

It said:

[image]

Be where?

I looked further down the note and saw something strange. It had a piece of music taped to it:

[image]

Below in a scribble it said:

[image]

I'm not sure what all this meant. So I continued to look at the note.

I turned the paper over and my heart sank. It was a blueprint of the very building I was in!

Below the blueprint was an object and strange text circled.

[image]

Were these instructions on when to rob this bank?!

I had to solve the puzzle so I could go to the police. But how to solve it?

So answer me this:

> What time was the heist?
>
> What were they going to steal?

Hint 0:

> The **:** in the music staff normally means repeat, it does not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They were stealing

> a diamond at 23:25.

The notes read

> AABBAABA AABBAABB : AABBAABA AABBABAB
>
>  Alpha Centauri A & B are a *binary* star system, hinting that we need to use binary to translate this.
>
>  So, convert to binary (A=0, B=1):
>  00110010 00110011 : 00110010 00110101
>
>  Which in ASCII reads **23:25**

Modified Newtonian Dynamics is

> abbreviated MOND, and prefixed with the "die" we get **diamond**.

Comment: Oh god, in my language we don't call that note `B` but `H`. That's not fair :)

Comment: @Sulthan Mine too ;)

Comment: That’s quite interesting!